Google Snap to Roads example output
I have been trying to use the example output of the Google Snap to Roads API as a test, but the only way it is recognized as a valid JSON file is if I remove all of the commas after placeid, ("placeId": "ChIJr_xl0GdNFmsRsUtUbW7qABM",).
Is this a mistake on my part? I would like to be able to use the test data without cleaning it of the commas.
I removed commands from the placeid and the very bottom brackets, and my program ran, however, when I didn't, it would not work.

Python can't parse JSON with extra trailing comma. Can json.loads ignore trailing commas?

Or use https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

If I were to use the python version, would the output still be a json? I'm just trying to get the lat/long of a road coordinate.
